# lmfit fits 'wrong' peak in data with multiple peaks

Tags: python, gaussian, lmfit

With this code (before the snippet I just read in the data, which works fine, and after the snippet I just do labels etc.)

```
plt.errorbar(xdata, ydata, yerr, fmt='.', label='Data')

model = models.GaussianModel()
params = model.make_params()

params['center'].set(6.5)
#params['center'].vary = False

fit = model.fit(ydata, params=params, x=xdata, weights=1/yerr)
print(fit.fit_report())

plt.plot(xdata, fit.best_fit, label='Fit')
```

I try to fit the last peak (approximately at x=6.5). But as you can see in the picture, the code does not do that. Can anyone tell me why that is?

[image]

**Edit:** If I run the line `params['center'].vary = False` the "fit" just becomes zero everywhere.

Comment: Try to restrict the fitting range or alternatively you can consider a superposition of two gaussian which may fit both peaks. The model consisting of one single bell curve is just not fitting you data as you cann see by eye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used [lmfit](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/parameters.html#lmfit.parameter.Parameters), but the problem is most likely, that you try to fit the whole data region. Considering the entire region of data you handed to the `.fit` call, the resulting fit is probably the best and correct.
You should try to pass only relevant data to the fit. In your case `xdata` should only be the set of data points from around 5.5 up to 7.5 (or somewhere around these numbers). `ydata` has to be adapted to these values as well, of course. Then the fit should work nicely.